# help finding virtual Turtlebot IP

Tags: simulation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking to simulate my turtlebot using gazebo for testing, and have been told that for the most part, working with the turtlebot in simulation is identical to working with the turtlebot hardware. My problem right now is that I need to get past the step in the tutorial where I am told to get the IP of the turtlebot using the laptop inside the robot, as my simulated robot does not have a laptop I can access.

How can I find what IP to use to connect to my simulated turtlebot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35490/help-finding-virtual-turtlebot-ip/) by [Intellethan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2518/intellethan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Ignore those network setup for simulating turtlebot in your system.

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2012-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1